# Facebook connect on Google App Engine with Django Patch

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, facebook

We are building a website on Google App Engine, using django patch.
We would like to use Facebook connect for two purposes:

1. Authenticate users.
2. Access user's social data.

Searching for a solution in the usual places (google, FB, SO) brigs up a lot of noise, many partial solutions and no clear answer.

So the question is this: does anyone has a clear working solution? maybe even a recipe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Honza: we where looking for something that also does authentication Django style.
We ended up doing the login on the client side than sending an AJAX request to Django and wrote our own authenticate/login logic.
Once we get the user's credentials, we use PyFacebook for FB connectivity.